# Comparing two different sized pandas Dataframes and to find the row index with equal values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare, equals

I need some help with comparing two pandas dataframe

I have two dataframes

The first dataframe is

```
df1 =
   a   b   c   d
0  1   1   1   1
1  0   1   0   1
2  0   0   0   1
3  1   1   1   1
4  1   0   1   0
5  1   1   1   0
6  0   0   1   0
7  0   1   0   1
```

and the second dataframe is

```
df2 = 
   a   b   c   d
0  1   1   1   1
1  1   0   1   0
2  0   0   1   0
```

I want to find the row index of dataframe 1 (df1) which the entire row is the same as the rows in dataframe 2 (df2). My expect result would be

```
0
3
4
6
```

The order of the above index does not need to be in order, all I want is the index of dataframe 1 (df1)

Is there a way without using for loop?

Thanks

Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='both'].index
Out[459]: Int64Index([0, 3, 4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Can I ask is there another way if my columns name of dataframe 2 (df2) is different to the columns name of dataframe 1 (df1), lets say [1 2 3 4] instead of [a b c d]

Comment: @TommyYip rename it , like , df2.columns=df1.columns

Comment: Can I ask if I use df1.drop([0]) to drop the first row of df1 dataframe without reseting the index (having the first row of df1 with index 1 instead of 0). Is there a way to compare df2 with df1 and obtain an output of the index of [3 4 6]. If I use the code you provided above, I get the output of [2 3 5]. It automatically reset the index of df1. Could you help me please.

Comment: @TommyYip in the mean time , reset_index of df1 or df2 , and get the the index by ['index']